# Rewire a ceiling light to a double socket

Tags: electrical, ceiling, light, uk, socket

Is it legal and safe to remove a light fitting and use the three standard wires to wire up a double socket or gang plug?  I want to mount  a projector exactly where my light fitting is in the way.

Comment: Please add more info.  Is the light fixture on the wall or ceiling?  Is it attached to a recessed round box?

Comment: Legal depends on your location and if you own the property.  Safety depends if you know what you are doing.  Code requires at least one ceiling light or a switch outlet for a light in a room(I think).  Insurance might require an inspection.  Might need to add a separate outlet and box near the light, power taken from light box or new power cable added.

Comment: Thanks. I own the property.  It’s a new build and the light fitting is on the ceiling.  one live neutral and earth as opposed to loops that I wouldn’t go near.  I’ve replaced the fitting once from a rose to a fancy light and competent to do this as it’s a simple wiring job

Comment: If that is the only light on a wall switch in that room, then you might need to add an outlet near it, instead of removing the light fixture.

Comment: Not sure that helps.  I need that light gone as that’s where the projector needs to go.  My choice is fit a smaller light exactly there or if legal I prefer to use those wires to fit a two gang socket

Comment: Can move the light over and use that place for outlet.  Inspectors and insurance will probably need to see a working light controlled by wall switch.  Location of light is up to you, a ceiling light or desk lamp plugged into outlet controlled by switch.  If only one black and one white wire at light, then power goes to switch first then light.

Comment: When you replace that light with a projector socket, will there still be a light switch in the usual location that operates a light in the room?  Switching a receptacle is also acceptable.

Comment: @Paul_176 **Where is this?** Your use of "socket" instead of "receptacle" indicates the UK, and the Part P Wiring Regulations and Part L Lighting Regulations are probably not the same as their US counterparts.

Comment: Hi. Yes uk. I hope to swap the light fitting for a double uk 3 pin socket

Comment: Do you intend to run your projector off the lighting circuit? To be switched on with the light switch? Are there any other lights in the room? Are they controlled from the same switch (or via a different switch in a multi-gang switchplate)? Do you intend to use a standard 13A BS1363 socket, or a BS546 2A socket? Please add detail to the question! (I don't think you can do what you want to do, but more details are necessary to be sure.)

Answer (score 1):

A standard double socket is designed to deliver 20A, but a typical UK lighting circuit is only 6A. It's not actually wrong to connect a socket to an under-rated supply. But somebody might be in for a surprise if they plugged in a high power appliance and all the lights went out.

Labelling the socket would be a good idea.

If the installation is ever inspected, and if your lighting wires are only 1mm sq., rather than 1.5mm sq. then that could be a failure, because you're not supposed to use the smaller cable for power circuits.